# JQuery upgrade to version to v1.9.0 to avoid the vulnerable to Cross-site Scripting (XSS) attacks

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Currently the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR (v2.4.3) is using jQuery v1.6.4, which is reported as vulnerable to Cross-site Scripting (XSS) attack by the Component Governance task in the ADO. Is there any timeline or road map to upgrade the JQuery version to 1.9.0 (or higher)?

**Component Governance Report:**
jQuery before 1.9.0 is vulnerable to Cross-site Scripting (XSS) attacks. The jQuery(strInput) function does not differentiate selectors from HTML in a reliable fashion. In vulnerable versions, jQuery determined whether the input was HTML by looking for the '<' character anywhere in the string, giving attackers more flexibility when attempting to construct a malicious payload. In fixed versions, jQuery only deems the input to be HTML if it explicitly starts with the '<' character, limiting exploitability only to attackers who can control the beginning of a string, which is far less common.

Expecting the package with jQuery update to latest version